# Populating an HTML select list from a PHP array

Tags: php, html

I am trying to populate an HTML select list using an array of customer names. I am using the following code, but it does not seem to work. I have a function that query an SQL Server database and gets the names. I know that works fine as I am using it in other code, for some reason when I try to populate the select list it is coming up blank. Would it be better or more efficient to use a `for` loop? What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
<select name="customers">
    <?php
    $custNames = getCustomers();
    foreach($custNames as $customers){
        echo '<option value="' . $customers . '">' . $customers . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you see when you var_dump() $custNames? It may well be a multi-dimensional array or just not what you think it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried doing a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of `$custNames`. There's nothing wrong with your foreach loop, so most likely the `getCustomers()` function is returning a non-array, or an empty array.

And of course, be very careful inserting text that way. A single double-quote in any of the customer names will hose your form:

```
<option value="John "The Unknown" Doe">John "The Unknown" Doe</option>
```

At least pass the value portion through `htmlspecialchars()` to make it a bit safer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found when i used var_dump that it came back empty, when i looked further back I found an error in my typing that did not include my functions. It was an easy mistake but when your looking at something for a while I skipped over it a bunch of times. Thanks for the help, i appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for the tip on htmlspecialchars() also!

Answer (score 0):

A `foreach` loop is perfectly fine, provided that `getCustomers()` is returning an array (or more specifically, an object that implements the `Traversable` interface). You may wish to do a `var_dump( $custNames );` to check that what you have is in fact an array, otherwise you'll probably want to change the `getCustomers()` function to return an array.